# DBeaver quoting tables and columns when not needed

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

I recently updated to DBeaver Community Version 23.1.1.202306251800. I guess that this issue is linked to that release, though I'm not certain.

When I dragged a table from the Database Navigator to a SQL editor tab in the past, I would get a value like this: `CADDI_DEMO.CREDITCARDS.CREDIT_CARD_ACCOUNT`

Today I get a value like this: `"CADDI_DEMO"."CREDITCARDS"."CREDIT_CARD_ACCOUNT"`.

Both are valid, but I prefer the former. Is there a configuration option somewhere to return to the former?

NOTE: in general DBeaver is great about giving me `TABLE_NAME` in general but `"Table Name"` when the table contains spaces or other tricky bits. I have not changed my options as far as I know. But the behavior changed. At the moment it is quoting all of my column names as well. Yuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in Version 23.1.0.202306041918.
I got this slightly unusual log from my homebrew upgrade today:

```
==> Upgrading 3 outdated packages:
dbeaver-community 23.1.1 -> 23.1.0
```

Eventually I found it: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/20391

It was a Snowflake-only issue, which I had not realized.